# How to persist a Map<Key, Boolean> with the JPA

Tags: java, jpa, boolean, persistence

I have an Class in Java an their instances are JPA-`@Enitit[ies]`, but they cannot be persisted, because I get a `MappingException`, because I have a map:

```
private Map<Account, Boolean> doneTask;
```

And I do not know how to persist a `Boolean` like a `boolean`.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use [ElementCollection](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ElementCollection.html)?
Something like:

```
@ElementCollection
@JoinTable(name="TASKS", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="ID"))
@MapKeyColumn (name="ACCOUNT")
@Column(name="DONE_FLAG")
private Map<Account, Boolean> doneTask;
```

Comment: actually I did not. Thank You!